# Beta program site separation

Tags: java, proxy, beta

I have a site and i need to create a beta program for it. The idea is separate it in two distinct sites, one running stable application and the other the beta application.

The problem is that the URL to access stable or beta applications has to be the same and based on some rules, like header value, request body or query param the request will be forwarded to the correct site.

I tried Apache mod_proxy module, but it doesn't have the option to create specific rules, like those i need.

Can you help me with it? Any ideas how to implement that?

Comment: Have you tried nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Nginx as the front end server. And configure it to redirect to stable or beta on base of header value.

Comment: I'm searching about it! I didn't find a module that allows fine grained control to the rules i need to apply. A solution that i found, is to use https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy as proxy. I'm experimenting yet!

Comment: At the end, I stayed with the Nginx running on FreeBSD and with a lua module to parse the body of the request and check the information I needed. Thank you!